# Подключение библиотеки Geometry (Google Maps Javascript API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как к API JavaScript добавить библиотеку Geometry? Что-то у меня не получается совсем.

Мой API:

```js
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>
```

Добавляю так:

```js
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry&sensor=false&language=en"
                    async defer></script>
```

Не работает...

Comment: Вы задали на сайте 144 вопроса. Неужели вы до сих пор не научились их задавать и описывать конкретные проблемы ошибки и то, в чем именно выражается "не работает"?

Comment: `YOUR_API_KEY` - сюда вы вставляете свой апи код? Хорошо бы узнать какую ошибку выдает.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk :)))да ключ я поставил а ошибки нету .консоль чиста но карта не отображается

Comment: ну так что бы карта появилась ее инициализировать нужно. Вы `function initMap()` прописали? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=ru

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk все это есть)Сорри не заметил ошибка такая

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()